# Hide subdirectory in WordPress using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Want to hide a subdirectory in WordPress installation.

**Folder is in root and this is how it looks right now**

http://test.domain.com/foldername

**But I want to hide the subdirectory for homepage and inner pages and should look like below**

http://test.domain.com/

Here is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?pma.ceffectz.com/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pmawp88/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pmawp88/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?pma.ceffectz.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pmawp88/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: @starkeen see above post I have added the code on top.

Comment: Don't post your code as a comment, edit your original post and add in additional information. I have help you to add your .htaccess info as part of your post this time. You should change your root directory in your Apache setting to the test.domain.com/foldername than do it at .htaccess.

Comment: @hcheung Yes I was trying to fix it then you came for help, thanks, between  I'm trying this in a cPanel Hosting server, not sure how to locate, all I see is Apache Handler

Answer (score 0):

If http://test.domain.com/foldername is your base website and you would like the folder to be accessed with the URL http://test.domain.com/ instead you need to edit your Apache or Nginx configuration and change the document root to include `foldername`: `/path/you/have/today/foldername/`

Then re-start your web server and you are good to go

Comment: I'm trying this in a cPanel Hosting server, not sure how to locate, all I see is Apache Handler

Comment: https://www.servint.net/university/article/the-tech-bench-changing-a-document-root-in-cpanel/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !subfolder /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Just replace **subfolder** with your actual folder.

This will internally forward your root folder to **/subfolder**

Comment: What do you mean by "didnt work" ? Actually, this rewrites domain.com/ to domain.com/subfolder. What happens when you type domain.com/ in your browser address bar?